# What is the meaning of this analogy?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> This chapter is describing the character of Sonny, the eldest son of Godfather, who is known for his aggressiveness.

Then it went on and said

> ”...his martyred wife feared the marriage bed as unbelievers once feared the rack.”

Is it talking about the atheist? And the rack is the penalty or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. An unbeliever is an atheist, and the rack was a contraption used for punishment many centuries ago. 
[The rack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_(torture))

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is full of metaphor.

A person who is "martyred" is originally a Christian who was tortured or killed instead of changing their religion. But here it means a person who suffers, an example of *hyperbole* It suggests that he is cruel to his wife.

She fears the "marriage bed". This is an example of *Synecdoche*, (or at least *Metonymy*) in which "the marriage bed" represents the whole action of sex. Perhaps he forces her to have sex with him.

The "rack" is a torture device in which the victim is painfully stretched by means of ropes tied to their arms and legs. They would be stretched until their joints dislocated or tore. It was particularly used by the Inquisition who searched for heretics in Medieval Europe. Victims (more likely Protestants than atheists) would often be forced to witness others being tortured on the rack to get them to confess. So the rack would be greatly feared. This *simile* says that the "marriage bed" is like the rack.